# Getting The payment attempt failed because of an invalid payment method. error in stripe laravel cashier

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-8

I am Getting The payment attempt failed because of an invalid payment method. error in stripe laravel cashier. I am doing everything according to the laravel stripe cashier documentation.

```php
public function orderPost(Request $request) {
    $user = auth()->user();
    $paymentMethod = $request->paymentMethod;
    Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_51AKI9PG7pDGBBGY5eNZ8XBOF8HKjTQm9zXUFz4Ww72a3m73jOwDd75FgyDGmsYCxJ68vCuCVX8MmUujJDpCn41oc00TF5O4giI');
    if (is_null($user->stripe_id)) {
        $stripeCustomer = $user->createAsStripeCustomer();
    }
    $user->updateDefaultPaymentMethod($paymentMethod);
    $user->newSubscription('main','price_1IIAk5G7pDGBBGY50mjUUlhj')
        ->create($paymentMethod, [
            'name' => 'Tom Tom',
            'description' => 'test description',
            'email' =>'tomtom@gmail.com',
            "address" =>'VPO DLLDOD DOLODO'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: First off, you should roll your key immediately. Even if it's just a test key malicious people can now ruin your test data. To address your issue, what's the exact error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this :
If you have added trial periods in your subscriptions :

```
 $user->newSubscription('main','price_1IIAk5G7pDGBBGY50mjUUlhj')
        ->trialDays($trialDays) //Trial days of particular subscription 
        ->create($paymentMethod, [
            'name' => 'Tom Tom',
            'description' => 'test description',
            'email' =>'tomtom@gmail.com',
            "address" =>'VPO DLLDOD DOLODO'
 ]);
```

If trial periods ends or you're purchasing for second time :

```
$user->newSubscription('main','price_1IIAk5G7pDGBBGY50mjUUlhj')
        ->trialDays(0)
        ->create($paymentMethod, [
            'name' => 'Tom Tom',
            'description' => 'test description',
            'email' =>'tomtom@gmail.com',
            "address" =>'VPO DLLDOD DOLODO'
 ]);
```